# Trouble w/ Haskell Implementation of Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: haskell, crt

So I am having a problem trying to implement the Chinese Remainder Theorem into Haskell. So far I have this:

```
minv :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
minv a m = let (1, x, _) = extGCD a m
           in x `mod` m


crt :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer
crt as ms = let
                    prod = product ms
                    big_m = [div prod i| i <- ms]
            in (zip as ms (\(ai,mi)) ((ai * big_m * (minv mi big_m)) `mod` prod))
```

Okay so I know the `minv` function works (I've tested it multiple times), but I can't get the `crt` function to work. So here is what I am trying to do:

I need to zip list `as` and `ms` together and then apply each one of the binaries to the equation that actually finds the Chinese Remainder Theorem. But I need to handle the binaries first and THEN apply `` `mod` prod `` to the ENTIRE number I get from working all the binaries.

Hopefully this make some form of sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, it'll be easier in the long run to indent with spaces instead of tabs.  It's possible to use tabs in Haskell, but the interpreter always sees them as the equivalent of 8 spaces.  I'd really recommend using spaces because this can sometimes lead to problems when your editor makes it look like something is indented properly but the compiler doesn't agree.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're experiencing?  Is it producing the wrong output or are there errors?  I'm going to guess errors because `zip as ms <something>` probably won't compile since `zip` only takes 2 arguments and always returns a list, which also doesn't take any arguments.  On top of that, `(\(ai, mi))` is not a lambda function, you need a `->` in there somewhere followed by an expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from your problems expressing this as Haskell, I see two plain mathematical problems here related to the Chinese Remainder Theorem formula itself:

1. You probably want `minv big_m mi`, not `minv mi big_m`.
2. You have no function for summing up the list of terms.  For this you can use the Haskell function `sum`.

So, you first want to get the expression `ai * big_m * (minv big_m mi)` applied to each pair of elements in the lists `as` and `ms`.  It is useful for clarity to define this as a named function by itself, let's call it `term`:

```
    term ai mi = ai * big_m * (minv big_m mi)
```

(Note I am *not* putting `ai` and `mi` in a tuple, as the function we will use to zip later does not use them.)

However, the way you have defined `big_m` it is not a number, but the list

```
    big_m = [div prod i| i <- ms]
```

What you actually need `big_m` to be is the particular element of that list that matches with `ai` and `mi`, and which is equal to `div prod mi`.  Since this is a function of `mi`, it is simplest to define it inside the definition of `term`:

```
    term ai mi = let big_m = div prod mi
                 in ai * big_m * (minv big_m mi)
```

(I actually prefer `where` to `let` myself, but I've decided to use `let` since you did in the question.)

Now you need to apply the function `term` to all the corresponding elements from `as` and `ms`.  You could fix your original method by combining `zip` with the `map` function, something like

```
map (\(ai,mi) -> term ai mi) (zip as ms)
```

Note the lambda function syntax, which @bheklilr pointed out you had wrong.  Although the tuple confuses matters here, an ordinary lambda function needs no parentheses inside, and must have both `\` and `->`.

However, Haskell has a handy function `zipWith` that does both in one go (and doesn't need the function to take tuples):

```
zipWith term as ms
```

Then you need to use `sum` to sum the terms in the list thus constructed.

```
sum (zipWith term as ms)
```

Finally you can now apply the final `` `mod` prod `` to this:

```
sum (zipWith term as ms) `mod` prod
```

Combining all of this, the final `crt` function can become

```
crt :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer
crt as ms = let
                prod = product ms
                term ai mi = let big_m = div prod mi
                             in ai * big_m * (minv big_m mi)
            in sum (zipWith term as ms) `mod` prod
```

Comment: Not that it's your responsibility to check this, but an additional point for the topic starter that even this implementation does not correctly compute the solution to CRT. @eLemonnader needs to check the equations once more. It looks like in the original post one of `*` must be a division, and maybe more.

Comment: @SassaNF Um I *did* check my final `crt` implementation, admittedly on only one test case.  Just did another and that worked too.  Note that `minv` is modular inverse, so it essentially does the necessary division. (One of the reasons I answered this question was that I recognized `minv` and `extGCD` as a couple functions I already had in my personal "useful trinkets" module, so that I *would* be able to test the solution.)

Comment: Note when checking that the `ms` must be relatively prime, otherwise the algorithm won't work even if there is a solution.

Comment: @SassaNF Also I *did* fix a couple of mathematical bugs, see the top of my post.

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the order of values in the tuple from `extGCD`.

Comment: @SassaNF Right, my own version also had a different order, but the OP said `minv` was definitely working correctly so I adjusted for that.

Comment: Holy crap that was an amazing answer. Thank you so much guys, and especially Johansen.

Comment: @eLemonnader you should "accept" the most helpful answer by clicking the big green empty outline of a V check-mark next to the answer, to show your thanks and also to signal that the issue has been resolved (you'll get +2 rep bump for it, too).