# Haskell RSA Encryption Key Generator Trouble

Tags: function, haskell, rsa, generator

Okay so I am trying to create a basic RSA function into Haskell. It doesn't take string, only numbers. The trouble I am having right now is the key generator function. Here is what I have so far:

```
chooseKeys :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer)
chooseKeys n e = 
    let
      n' = (n-1)*(e-1)
      m  = (n*e)
      e' = find (e `mod` n') -- e' needs to be such that the gcd of (e',n') = 1
      d' = minv n' e'
      find x
        | g == 1 = x
        | otherwise = find ((x+1) `mod` n')
        where (g,_,_) = extGCD x n'
    in (e', d')
```

I know my 'minv' function is fine, but I don't think it is spiting out the right value. The program runs, but it doesn't give my the write answer. Could someone give some much appreciated help? Thanks!

EDIT: I modified the code a little bit. Hopefully it is a little clearer now.

Comment: Could you give some sample inputs with the expected results? Or, better, a link to a specification of the function you're trying to write?

Comment: You have ```e' = e `mod` n'```, where `gcd e' n' == 1`.  Why don't you write a function like [this](https://gist.github.com/46745c5b6aa9d1a3ba29), if it returns `Nothing` then you know your problem is with `e` and `n'`, otherwise you know it's fine and you can try other computations in your code to see if they're causing problems.

Comment: This all seems wrong. If `n` and `e` are _the_ primes, then GCD of `n'` and `e == mod e n'` is going to be 1 (for non-trivial `n`), so `e' == e`. You don't want to expose one of _the_ primes as the key. What is typically done, is `e'` is chosen to be a prime with a small number of ones - e.g. 3, 5 or 11. Its size in bits does not matter, because it is public anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall my RSA correctly, you want `` d' * e' `mod` n' == 1 ``.

Given this, and assuming this is the same `minv` as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007245/trouble-w-haskell-implementation-of-chinese-remainder-theorem), I think you have its arguments reversed.